# saveAll method in hibernate to update insert timestamp

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Have a class called `events` which is a many-to-one mapping to class `location`

using hibernate and spring.

when I use `eventsDao.saveAll(entities);` insert timestamp is created only for the first object in the list.

This is how timestamp looks in my mapping file,

```
<property name="insertTime" type="org.joda.time.contrib.hibernate.PersistentLocalDateTime" column="INSERTTIME"/>
```

How can I change it to save the insert timestamp for all the objects in the list? any suggestions please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you would do it with annotations.  Not sure what the equivalent is with xml configuration.  You can just create a new Date() whenever your instance is created, and then update the updated field whenever the entity gets updated:

```
private Date created = new Date();
private Date updated = new Date();

@PreUpdate
public void setLastUpdate() {  this.updated = new Date(); }
```

Don't provide a setter for any of these methods, only getters.

Comment: did helped man! overrided my saveAll method to update the time with getUpdateTime() and which worked! thanks a ton!